# Looping to make outputs centered

Tags: php, wordpress, algorithm, sorting

- I want to display all my categories in one page, 4 items per row.
- If I have 4,8 or 12 items then I have no problem, however if I have 5 items or any "number of items" that is not divisible by 4 without any remainder appears on the next row (as I have set each item 25% of the screen with css) with subsequent gap space which looks really odd and empty. This is a problem and I call those remainder items **indeBox** as in independent boxes.
- My end goal is to align those independent boxes on the centre.
- I am trying to create an algorithm for this purpose.

#### Here is what I have done so far

The following function takes two parameters.
  numberRestriction is the number of items allowed per row (4)
  childrens is an object with all categories.
  I am counting how many categories are present within the childrens object 
  and finding out if there are remainders.

```
function calculateDivision($numberRestriction, $childrens)
{

    $arrayobj = new ArrayObject($childrens);
    $itemLenght = $arrayobj->count();   

    $itemBasket = $itemLenght;
    $remaining = $itemBasket % $numberRestriction;

    return $remaining;
}
```

### On the template

```
 <?php 
    //$term = get_queried_object();
        $childrens = get_categories(array('parent'  => 27,'hide_empty' => false)); 
        $rowRestriction =4;
        $indeBox = calculateDivision($rowRestriction, $childrens); 

        $arrayobj = new ArrayObject($childrens);
        $itemLenght = $arrayobj->count();  
        $i = 0;


        if($indeBox == 0)
        {

            foreach($childrens as $index => $children) 
            {  
                $cat_image = z_taxonomy_image_url($children->term_id);
                $cat_id = $children->term_id;
                $desc = @explode('|', $term->description);  


                ?>



                <a  href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat_id) ?>" >
                <div class="food_list_single menus_list" style="background: url(<?php echo $cat_image ?>) no-repeat scroll right center / cover ">
                    <div class="food_hover menus_hover ">
                        <p style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; padding: 10px; text-align: center;" class="food_hover_title_small"><?php echo $desc[2] ?></p>
                        <p class="food_hover_title"><?php echo $children->name ?></p>
                        <button class="btn btn-default food_button"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i>View Details</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
                </a>



                <?php 
            } //foreach ends
        }else
        {

            //loop all items 
            //set a counter
            //everytime the counter reaches maximum item allowed in a row, counter should reset and add class to row even
            //once it finds odd number in a row it should call the row uneven
            $counter1 = 0;
            foreach($childrens as $index => $children) 
            {
                $counter1++;

                $cat_image = z_taxonomy_image_url($children->term_id);
                $cat_id = $children->term_id;
                $desc = @explode('|', $term->description);  

                    //out put div
                    ?>
                        <a  href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat_id) ?>" >
                        <div class="food_list_single menus_list" style="background: url(<?php echo $cat_image ?>) no-repeat scroll right center / cover ">
                            <div class="food_hover menus_hover ">
                                <p style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; padding: 10px; text-align: center;" class="food_hover_title_small"><?php echo $desc[2] ?></p>
                                <p class="food_hover_title"><?php echo $children->name ?></p>
                                <button class="btn btn-default food_button"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i>View Details</button>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        </a>


                    <?php
                    //also track the last items index
                    $last_items_index = $index;



            ?>




            <?php

            }
            echo "Inde items :".$indeBox; //finds how many indeboxes
            echo " Last items index " . $last_items_index ; 



        }


        ?>
```

### Image

[image: The screenshot of the page where I am outputing, notice last item is independent, i want to make it centerized]

Comment: Here is what I am thinking of
1) Find if there are indeboxes.
2) If there are then how many
3) Target that many items at the bottom part of the row 
4) Switch case 1,2,3 

does this sounds suitable? I am missing something

Comment: Most sites left-justify the remainders, just as shown in your image. Centering them might confuse your users who are used to the other way.

Comment: Can't you just create a `div` with a `text-align:center`?

Comment: No. I tried css, did not solve my problem as these are image based boxes. However, I found a solution.  It is not a great solution but it works. I will add it later as an answer

Answer (score 0):

### Solution: Not beautiful or efficient, but it works

1. Find out how many items in the array attach to a variable.
2. Find out how many boxes fit in a row and attach to a variable.
3. Calculate independent boxes using following function:

.

```
function calculateDivision($numberRestriction, $childrens)
{

    $arrayobj = new ArrayObject($childrens);
    $itemLenght = $arrayobj->count();   

    $itemBasket = $itemLenght;
    $remaining = $itemBasket % $numberRestriction;

    return $remaining;
}
```

Since I already know 4 boxes fit in a row, so there can only be either 1,2 or 3 independent boxes. and if there are 4 boxes then there are no independent boxes. I can run conditions

```
if($indeBox == 1)
{
 //if there are one independent box remaining 
 //find the last item of the array and put a bootstrap class col-md-offset-3 to 

 //if not last item, no need for adding additional class 

}
else if($indeBox == 2)
{
 //if there are two independent boxes remaining 
 //find the second last item of the array and put a bootstrap class col-md-offset-3 to 

 //if not last item, no need for adding additional class 
}
else if($indeBox == 3)
{
 //if there are three independent box remaining 
 //find the third last item of the array and put a bootstrap class col-md-offset-3 to 

 //if not last item, no need for adding additional class 
}
```